# iPhone 5 show iOS old iOS (9.3.5) as available update not the latest iOS (10.0)

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

My iPhone 5S shows iOS 10.0 in available update but for iPhone 5 it shows different. It shows iOS 9.3.5.

What's is the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The iPhone already downloaded the 9.3.5 update and can't download / install iOS 10 until that is dealt with. Either remove this download from the iPhone, or install the update and later update to iOS 10.

To delete the update:

- Go to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage.
- Tap Delete Update, and tap Delete Update again to confirm.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't show as an available Download but rather shows that it's already downloaded and is waiting for you to hit the *Install Now* button so what you'd like to do is navigate to Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage under the STORAGE group and you could then delete the downloaded update.

You would then check again for an available update and iOS 10.0.1 should show up.